# addClass() isnt working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Okay so i dont know exactly whats happening here, i am trying to make a string of text look like its been highlighted with a cursor blinking. Like when you click on text in your browser search bar and see it blinking every second.

```
window.setInterval(function(){
if($('.cursorBlink').hasClass('blink')){
    $('.cursorBlink').addClass('blinkOff');
}


if($('.cursorBlink').hasClass('blinkOff')){
    $('.cursorBlink').removeClass('blinkOff').addClass('blink');
}
}, 1000);
```

So as you can see i set a window setInterval so every second it will remove and add two different classes. One with a left border and one without. So this code does not work, however the strange thing is if i put an alert(); in the functions it makes the whole thing work correctly which is confusing.

Please see my jsfiddle, it has the alert() in the function to show you it working (set to every 3 seconds so it doesn't annoy you).

[**Fiddler**](https://jsfiddle.net/4eecdcot/2/)

Comment: Maybe use if(){} **else** (){}  ...

Comment: You never remove class `blink` so first condition is always truthly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic of your code is a little confusing. So confusing in fact that I'm not even sure of its point when you can make this a single call using `toggleClass()`:

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    $('.cursorBlink').toggleClass('blinkOff');
}, 3000);
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4eecdcot/3/)

Also note that you can avoid the little jump that happens when the class is removed by setting the colour of the border to transparent instead of removing it:

```
.blinkOff {
    border-left-color: transparent;
}
```

Finally, this can be done in CSS alone, without any JS at all:

```
.blink {
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    animation: blinker 6s step-start infinite;
}
@keyframes blinker {  
  50% { border-left-color: transparent; }
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4eecdcot/8/)

Comment: I'd also change the css .blinkOff {border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);} just so it doesn't shift the whole line each time.

Answer (score 3):

You add the class `blinkOff` then you **immediately** test to see if it has the `blinkOff` class and, if it does (and it **always** does because you just added it), then you remove it again.

You need to change your code from:

```
if () { }
if () { }
```

to

```
if () { }
else { }
```

or at least

```
if () { }
else if () { }
```

Comment: In fact OP never removes class `blink`, his logic is really failing. I still not get it reading - rereading question again and again

Answer (score 1):

Think better your logic. Look at this:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    if($('.cursorBlink').hasClass('blink')){
        $('.cursorBlink').addClass('blinkOff');
        $('.cursorBlink').removeClass('blink');

    }else{
        $('.cursorBlink').addClass('blink');
        $('.cursorBlink').removeClass('blinkOff');
    }
}, 3000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jsmhxkby/

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, if you replace the second if with an else it should work fine. Otherwise, both the 'if' will run everytime

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    if($('.cursorBlink').hasClass('blink')){
        $('.cursorBlink').removeClass('blink').addClass('blinkOff');
    }
    else{
        $('.cursorBlink').removeClass('blinkOff').addClass('blink');
    }
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case second if is running soon after first if, it is removing first added class. According to your requirement, it should be like this:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    if($('.cursorBlink').hasClass('blink')){
       $('.cursorBlink').removeClass('blink').addClass('blinkOff');
    }        
    else {
        $('.cursorBlink').removeClass('blinkOff').addClass('blink');
    }
  }, 1000);
```

Answer (score -1):

Rory's solution is correct. You can modify your existing code to

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    if($('.cursorBlink').hasClass('blinkOff')){
        $('.cursorBlink').removeClass('blinkOff').addClass('blink');
    }
    else {
        $('.cursorBlink').removeClass('blink').addClass('blinkOff');
    }
}, 3000);
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4eecdcot/5/)